# Euler Lagrange problem while keeping the integral of the function constant

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm looking for a function $y(x)$ which minimizes following equation
$$
\int_0^L(y''(x)-f(x))^2dx
$$
under the constraints that
$$
\int_0^Ly(x)dx=A\\
y(x\in[0,L])>0 \\
y(0)=0\\
y(L)=0\\
$$
with $f(x)$ being known function that I will be plugging in later, however, I can't figure what equations I should be solving. If I understand correctly the Lagrange multipliers can't be used here, as my condition is for the value of the integral, and not for the value of the function for every given $x$.

Could someone point me in the right direction about what I should be reading about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the extremals of the functional
$$
\int\limits_0^L(y''(x)-f(x))^2+\lambda y(x))\,dx
$$
For a reference, you can check Gelfand-Fomin, section 12. (page 43 in my edition)

Observe that here $\lambda$ is a constant, not a function of $x$ as it is the case when you have finite (non-integral) subsidiary conditions.

Comment: If I understand this correctly this will give me a solution parametrised by $\lambda$. Do I then use area conservation condtition to find what is the value of the $\lambda$?

Comment: You are right. Your new minimization problem (including $\lambda$) plus the boundary conditions plus the integral subsidiary condition determine both the extremals and $\lambda$, just like in the finite-dimensional case.